# Remote MongoLab MongoDB login failed error

Tags: mongodb, mlab

I am trying to connect to a mongoLab mongoDB using mongo shell. This is the error that I am getting:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\bin>mongo ds053332.mongolab.com:53332/stormaxdb -u abhishek -p password
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.4
connecting to: ds053332.mongolab.com:53332/stormaxdb
2015-03-18T16:44:27.740+0530 Socket recv() errno:10053 An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.     54.224.106.116:53332
2015-03-18T16:44:27.742+0530 SocketException: remote: 54.224.106.116:53332error: 9001 socket exception [RECV_ERROR] server     [54.224.106.116:53332]
2015-03-18T16:44:27.746+0530 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
2015-03-18T16:44:27.748+0530 Error: 10276 DBClientBase::findN: transport error: ds053332.mongolab.com:53390 ns: stormaxdb.$cmd query: { getnonce: 1 } at src/mongo/sh
ell/db.js:1210
exception: login failed
```

I searched a lot to fix this error but did not find a concrete solution. Can anybody guide how to solve it, and why is it coming?

Comment: This seems to be a problem with your Windows, possibly network connectivity issue. You need to make sure that you have the proper network access. You can check basic network access and DNS resolution by just pinging your database server. For example: `% ping ds053332.mongolab.com`. If the test above fails, check your network connection and your DNS settings if you’re using a custom DNS.

Comment: I tried that, it is working fine. I also tried port forwarding but it also did not work.

Comment: Can you connect to the port by using nc or netcat? `% nc -w 3 -v ds053332.mongolab.com 53332` Also, I think you should [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29120860/edit) your question to include what you have tried to resolve this so that you may increase the possibilities of getting working solutions, else you may need to log in a support ticket to MongoLab.

Comment: Yeah I also tried that but it did not work. Sent a support mail to mongolab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar issue. It appeared that my firewall was blocking connection to mongo server. Try unblocking mongo from the firewall settings and it should work.